# MVC Breakpoints and crossing projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

My VS Community 2015 is doing some really weird stuff. I am using iisexpress and this has happened in IE, Firefox, and VS internal browser. I deleted the temporary ASP.NET files , Built and Rebuilt the solution and deleted the bin and obj folders.

1. My Controller breakpoints are not being hit even though the symbols are loaded (the circles are red). I closed and reopened VS and then the project had to be moved to a different solution entirely and the breakpoints are still not being hit. I cleaned the solution. VS is in debug mode. If I update the cshtml file that the controller refers to the view is updated. My project is set to be the start up project and this is happening with the auto-generated code for the About page.

   ```
       public ActionResult About()
       {
           ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";//my breakpoint is here

           return View();
       }
   ```

View

```
@{
       ViewBag.Title = "About";
     }
      <h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
      <h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>
      <p>Use this area to provide information.</p>
```

And

```
     @{
         ViewBag.Title = "About";
      }
         <h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
         <h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>
         <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
```

show two different pages.

2. The auto-generated Contact page has a break point that isn't getting hit. Not sure why, but additionally it is not showing my Contact view rather, it uses a redirect from a different project in the same solution. This project is *not* the startup project.
   Controller from start up project

   ```
   public ActionResult Contact()
   {
      ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";//my breakpoint is here
      return View();
   }
   ```

The redirect

```
   public ActionResult Contact()
   {
      return RedirectPermanent("http://mywebsite.com/");
   }
```

3. I tried to change the default page in the `RouteConfig` to a different controller and the controller is not the start page even though the `RouteConfig` says it should be. I am not sure if it is part of the same problem or something else entirely.

   ```
           public class RouteConfig
           {
              public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
              {
                 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

                 routes.MapRoute(
                    "Default",
                    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    new { controller = "MyControllerFile", action = "ControllerMethod", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                   new string[] { "MyProject.Controllers" }
               );
             }
          }
   ```

   Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you built or rebuilt?  There's an important distinction between the two.

Comment: @David L I have built and rebuilt.

Comment: Could you clean your solution and then hit build, also if you are using git, you could try to `clean` your repository, and then clean and rebuild again. If none of those work then perhaps you should take a look in the temp folder where razor compiles its views and stuff and see if there is something that might be getting your views mixed up

Comment: @Luiso I cleaned and then built as asked. Still no luck. I am using subversion but why would that make for a difference? The problem is my local copy. And where does razor compile? I thought it loads at runtime.

Comment: There should be no difference between svn or git, I'm just not sure svn has the *clean* feature. As for the razor compiled files, what razor does is that every `cshtml` file rendered is compiled into a class (`cs`) file and stored somewhere on the temp folder of your user, I was just saying that there might be something wrong with that, though highly unlikely